# How to create a choropleth of the world using d3?

Tags: dictionary, d3.js

[This tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/choropleth.html) is a great intro to creating choropleths with d3, but it's data is US-centric. Where do I get the corresponding data for a world map?

I'm sure it's in the docs somewhere, but I can't find it. [This](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections) is the closest I've found, but the one world map on there specifically says it's not recommended for choropleths. Also,

Comment: The reason the world map you found says it's not recommended for choropleths is because it's a mercator projection. The problem with this projection is that it distorts the areas; northernmost and southernmost regions appear disproportionately larger than regions near the middle. 

The page you found essentially claims that coloring each country based on some metric is a bit like comparing apples and oranges, because your audience might be mislead by the disproportionate sizes of regions and make some wrong assumptions about the data being represented by the colors.

Comment: That's not to say that there are any technical issues preventing you from being able to use that world map to create a choropleth map, but you have to be careful about the claims you're making with it. I don't know about any projections that maintain proportionality for the entire world without introducing other kinds of distortions. There are all kinds equal-area of projections described [on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equal-area), but they introduce other kinds of distortions. And... producing an SVG of one of those projections is probably not going to be easy.

Comment: @meetamit thanks. Yeah, I understand that. So even if I wanted to use that map, or another, where do I get the world equivalent of "../data/us-states.json"? Do I have to generate that myself? I guess I thought D3 had that kind of thing available as a plug-in or something. Seems like http://jvectormap.com/ is the easier way to go for my purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE: This answer was written for version 2 of d3. Version 3 is out now, and it has awesome new features that create better geometry segmentation and solve the fill issue mentioned below. Also, the interface for setting up projections _*may*_ have changed in V3 (not sure bc I haven't tried).**

There is a json file available for the entire world, and you can render it equivalently to the us-states.json coropleth (using an Albers equal area projection) – assuming you understand (and are ok with) the fact that an Albers-projected world map looks like [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlbersEqual-AreaConicProjection.html), which is not quite how most people recognize a world map.

First you need the [json data for the entire world](https://raw.github.com/mbostock/d3/master/examples/data/world-countries.json), which is the same data used by the [world mercator projection example](http://bl.ocks.org/2869760).

Then you need to render the world json data using a customized Albers projection:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mercator Projection</title>

<style>
  path {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
  }
</style>

<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  d3.json("world-countries.json", function(collection) {
    d3.select("svg").selectAll("path")
        .data(collection.features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(
          d3.geo.albers()
            .parallels([10, 80])
            .origin([0,40])
            .translate([500,250])
            .scale(100)
        ));
  });
</script>
```

`origin()`, `parallels()`, `translate()`, and `scale()` values can be tweaked to get different results.

There's a problem with Antartica, which – due to the nature of this projection – gets "flipped" and is not a closed shape, so its fill covers the whole world. You either have to remove it from the json, or don't apply fill to it.

Also for some reason Brazil (and couple of others) didn't get rendered properly when I tried this. Dunno why. You'd have to examine the svg and the data to figure out why.

Comment: Do you have also the list of the names of the countries associated to the ids, please?

Comment: @mellin all the data, including the names of countries, is inside the JSON file used by mbostock's example. This JSON: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/2869760/raw/c5094cef84e05315e37a3fa6afec54c5b5e6745c/readme.json